# Flash video gets sluggish while doing complex HTML content update

Tags: javascript, html, flash

Hi all: our users complain the flash video on the web page will get sluggish(stop for a short while) when we need to update HTML content of other area in the page. 
The update flow is like this:

1. Get JSON data via Ajax
2. Use a template to build the final HTML content based on the JSON data
3. Use $.html() to update a DIV region

Is there any way I can circumvent the sluggish issue? I hear about Web Worker, not sure whether it is a feasible solution.

Thanks for any suggestion,

Ricky

Comment: chances are it's the `$.html` that is causing the problem - because steps 1 and 2 shouldn't have any impact on a plugin - if so, web workers wont help - without ANY code to look at though, it's just speculation

Comment: Yes i am that one and that's going to be a challenge

Comment: @Ricky, You got a link to see this issue in action? Does having the Flash video load into an **iframe** help? My logic is that an **iframe** is an enitrely separate page to the main one so that separation of processes may help...

Comment: @VC.One: the site is for internal, not public. I will try your suggestion of separate frames.

Comment: Worth a try. It's only a theory. Also try loading the iframe (of Flash app) last when the rest page is ready.